# How to simulate an unhandled exception in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, exception

I am creating some multi-threaded code, and I have created a JobDispatcher class that creates threads. I want this object to handle any unhandled exceptions in the worker threads, and so I am using

```
Thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(this);
```

Now, I would like to test this functionality - how can I generate an unhandled exception in the run() method of my worker object?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just throw any exception.

E.g.:

```
throw new RuntimeException("Testing unhandled exception processing.");
```

Complete:

```
public class RuntimeTest
{
  public static void main(String[] a)
  {
    Thread t = new Thread()
    {
      public void run()
      {
        throw new RuntimeException("Testing unhandled exception processing.");
      }
    };
    t.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler()
    {
      public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e)
      {
        System.err.println(t + "; " + e);
      }
    });
    t.start();
  }
}
```

Comment: Eclipse won't let me compile when I do this - it insists I surround with try/catch. Do you know how to change this behavior?

Comment: It should compile.  Looks like some Eclipse-specific extra check.

Comment: Eclipse might complain if you have other code in a method after the throwing of the exception, make it the only/last line in the method it is in.

Comment: @Martin, you should be able to right click on the line where the unhandled exception is occurring and tell eclipse to ignore it.

Comment: Use `if (true) throw new RuntimeException("Melp");` else Eclipse/javac will indeed complain about unreachable code. Note that there's a subtle compiler difference between **runtime** exception and "normal" exception.

Comment: @Balus, pretty sure this is an Eclipse-specific issue.  I posted an example that always throws, has no conditional, and compiles in javac.

Answer (score 6):

What's the problem with just throwing an exception:

```
throw new Exception("This should be unhandled");
```

Inside your run method. And of course, not catching it. It should trigger your handler.

Answer (score 6):

You should throw some *unchecked exception*. An unchecked exception does not require your code to handle it, and is therefore a good candidate to make all the way down the call stack.

You can choose **RuntimeException** for example, or even something like **AssertionError**, if you want to minimize the chances that some part of the code catches the exception and handles it before it reaches your handler.

Answer (score 0):

just add this code and you'll get unhandled exception without lint error:

```
int i = 1/0;
```